# Can't include jquery in netbeans

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, netbeans

When I include a jQuery file like as follows in Netbeans, my code doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js">`
```

whereas it works when I proceed as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"'>
```

Does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Edited so that the code snippets do show up. Also did a little rephrasing.

Comment: Is there actually a JavaScript file at `js/jquery-1.3.2.js` in your project?  You changed from including a script over an external site to using one on your own server.  Make sure that you actually have that file where you are telling your webpage it is.

Comment: Adding with zero298, even if the file exists, it should be in the correct path. So in case your calling file is in a folder `myFolder` your jQuery should be in `myFolder/js` folder.

Comment: Yes, it is in correct path, this is the link : http://s14.postimg.org/qhqu6w7oh/Capture_d_e_cran_2015_12_30_a_01_44_41.png. The name of the project is jqproject, and my calling file isn't in a folder

Comment: try `jQuery` in your console if it returns object or undefined.

Comment: I finally change my local server, I used XAMPP. But I uninstalled it and install MAMP, now it 's quite OK

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jQuery, first, followed by your custom script file. If this order is reversed, your script will not run

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have the privilege for open the jquery file. If you have only read permission change it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the page being blank. I found that closing the tags like with the full `</script>` fixes the problem instead of `/ >`.

Before I had it like `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" />`

Seems Netbeans has an issue with shorthand closing of tags.

Hope this helps!